# Creating a permanent fold in vim/neovim

Tags: vim, latex, neovim

I'm using nvim to write up LaTeX documents and would like to be able to fold my 200 line preamble in such a way that if I close and reopen the file, the preamble will still be folded. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These commands will start tex files with all folds engaged:

```
augroup tex
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType tex setlocal foldmethod=marker
    " start out with everything folded away
    autocmd FileType tex setlocal foldlevel=0
    autocmd FileType tex setlocal foldlevelstart=0
augroup END
```

So if you use a marker (default `{{{` and `}}}`) around your preamble, this
will do the trick.